# ActiveAdmin index as a Leaflet map

Tags: ruby, leaflet, activeadmin

We are already using ActiveAdmin as a backend for our projects database, and we would like to add another view to the Index section that is basically a map that shows the location of each of them on a Leaflet map.

We've been looking at https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/3-index-pages.md, but still can't figure it out :(

Structurally, each project has a lat/long field.

Any ideas?

Comment: It'll be easier to create a custom page http://activeadmin.info/docs/10-custom-pages.html

Comment: True, but then we'd have to reimplement all the filters/scopes...

Comment: I am sure you have figured this out by now. But if not: do you mean that you what to add a column to each row that is a map with the project lat/long, right?

Answer (score 0):

Custom index views are built with [Arbre](https://github.com/activeadmin/arbre/).  There are various examples in the [ActiveAdmin source](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/tree/master/lib/active_admin/views/components)  Once you understand Arbre you can understand how the [index views](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/tree/master/lib/active_admin/views) are built.